# How is the callback function called in this OpenCV example?

Tags: c++, opencv

I started reading *Learning OpenCV 3* but since I haven't programmed much in c++ I am confused by the way of using a callback function in the following code snippet:

```
int g_slider_position = 0;
int g_run = 1, g_dontset = 0;
cv::VideoCapture g_cap;

void onTrackBarSlide(int pos, void *)
{
    g_cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos);
    if (!g_dontset) g_run = 1;
    g_dontset = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    g_cap.open(std::string(argv[1]));

    int frames = (int)g_cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

    cv::createTrackbar(
        "Position",
        "Example 2-4",
        &g_slider_position,
        frames,
        onTrackBarSlide
    );
    cv::Mat frame;
    for (;;)
    {
        if (g_run != 0)
        {
            g_cap >> frame;
            if (frame.empty())
            {
                break;
            }
            int current_pos = (int)g_cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
            g_dontset = 1;
            cv::setTrackbarPos("Position", "Example 2-4", current_pos);
            cv::imshow("Example 2-4", frame);
            g_run -= 1;
        }

        char c = (char)cv::waitKey(10);

        if (c == 's')
        {
            g_run = 1;
        }

        if (c == 'r')
        {
            g_run = -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I gather from this is that pressing somewhere on the *Trackbar* raises an event that calls `onTrackBarSlide`.

What I'm wondering there is where do the `int pos` argument come from? I couldn't find it on the function documentation.

When I step through this program `onTrackBarSlide` is called after `setTrackbarPos`. This confuses me and makes me think that `setTrackbarPos` is just raising an event with `current_pos` as the argument that `onTrackBarSlide` listens for.

But why couldn't it be done more directly by having `setTrackbarPos` call `g_cap.set` directly?

Comment: The callback is called whenever trackbar position changes (with the first parameter being the current position), and `setTrackbarPos` changes the trackbar position (just like moving it with a mouse would). | `setTrackbarPos` is a library function, there's no way it could be "aware" that something like `g_cap` exists. Even if it could access it, it wouldn't be very useful, as not everyone wants to use a trackbar to seek in a video. That's why the callback support is there - it allows the user to customize the behaviour, without the need to modify and rebuild the library.

Comment: When you say the current position what do you mean exactly? It has a pointer to `g_slider_position` so I'm assuming that's how it knows the current position? Will the `current_pos` be taken in as the argument after calling `setTrackbarPos`?

Comment: `g_slider_position` is not really necessary for that. The UI control from whatever backend is used (Windows,Qt, GTK, etc.) tracks the position internally and there are several ways to access it -- you can call `getTrackbarPos`, you can provide a pointer to variable in `createTrackbar` which will be automatically updated as the position is changed, or you can set a callback function, which will be called with the current position as the first parameter whenever the position changes.

Comment: It seems a lot of things are going on behind the scenes then and it's hard to get a good understanding without peeking behind those scenes. Do you know of any resource where I can look more into this on a general _c++_ level or as it relates to _OpenCV_?

Comment: Yep, GUI's are a non-trivial topic :) I can't think of any specific resource, but read up on event-driven programming, pick some GUI framework and start learning that. The language doesn't really matter, the principles are generally the same. At some point, it would be good idea to read through the sources of the revelant part of OpenCV highgui module. Expect that it will probably take a decent amount of work and time to learn and understand this topic.

Comment: The event-driven programming I've seen in a language like _Javascript_ has not really caused me that many problems so I think it might be something more specific to _c++_. I'll probably look into the _OpenCV_ sources if I still struggle with it. Thanks!

Comment: On my mac with opencv 3.4, the callback is not called. I doesn't know why